# React with eel - multiple pages

Tags: python, react-native, eel

So I have React application and I need to access another page from the navbar. I'm able to call another HTML file from "href" but then Python script (which uses eel) ends.

```
<Nav.Link href="/settings.html">Settings</Nav.Link>
```

("settings.html" loads successfully but then Python script ends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out. Had to use "react-router-dom".

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/installation